# google_play_scraper output to a csv

Tags: python

I have used the following function and need the get the "result" out in to a csv file.

```
from google_play_scraper import Sort, reviews_all

result = reviews_all('com.xxxx.xxxx',
    sleep_milliseconds=0, lang='en',sort=Sort.MOST_RELEVANT)
```

I want to have a csv as follows;

```
userName,rating,content,score
user1,5,textcontent,3
user2,4,textcontent,4
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your attempted solution at the problem before expecting users to resolve it for you.

Comment: Use the Pandas library [(docs)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from google_play_scraper import Sort, reviews_all

result = reviews_all('com.xxxx.xxxx',
    sleep_milliseconds=0, lang='en',sort=Sort.MOST_RELEVANT)

resultList = pd.DataFrame([result])
resultList.to_csv = (resultList.csv)
```

you can try this